# How to configure Git Project to fetch credentials automatically?

Tags: git, github

How to configure Git Project to fetch credentials automatically instead of repeatedly asking it everytime you push the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute the below command from the Git folder through command prompt

```
    git config credential.helper 'store [options]'
```

It will ask for credentials for the first time and from the next time it automatically fetches the information.

Reference: 
        https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-store